# tika merges words when words are inside a table

Tags: java, c#, apache-tika

I have the following problem:
Tika is merging two words into one when they are inside a table.
Below is a two by two table:

```
John        Smith

Jane        White
```

In that case, it will be merging SmithJane.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
var parser = new AutoDetectParser();
            var context = new ParseContext();
            context.set(typeof(Parser), parser);
            var handler = new BodyContentHandler(10 * 1024 * 1024);
            var metadata = new Metadata();
            var stream = TikaInputStream.get(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\Temp\file.pdf")); //attachmentFile is the file as an array of bytes
            try
            {
                parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.close();
            }

            var test = handler.toString();
```

Comment: What version of Apache Tika is this with? And if it isn't the most recent, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I'm using Tika 1.11. I believe that's the latest version.

Comment: What happens if you try playing with the PDF Config, eg [setSortByPosition](https://tika.apache.org/1.11/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParserConfig.html#setSortByPosition%28boolean%29) and [setSpacingTolerance](https://tika.apache.org/1.11/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParserConfig.html#setSpacingTolerance%28java.lang.Float%29)?

Comment: It seems the setSortByPosition(true) did the trick. I really appreciate your help! Can you explain why is that?

Comment: It's much slower, which is why it isn't on by default, but it allows working around some of the "odd" "features" of how the PDF format can work...

Comment: I was using the pddocument (PDFBox) for that, is there a way to do it using tika?